# invalid output by loop of creating objects

Tags: java

My program is supposed to total a persons commission and it just keeps outputting $0.0. I'm very perplexed. Here is my code. I have tried everything that I can think of to fix it. It is probably a small dumb mistake I have made, I'm just too tired to see it.

```
public class SalesComissionCalculator 
{
double item1;
double item2;
double item3;
double item4;
double finalamount;

public SalesComissionCalculator()
{
    item1 = 239.99;
    item2 = 129.75;
    item3 = 99.95;
    item4 = 350.89;
    finalamount = 0;
}
public void Additem(int input)
{
    if(input == 1)
        finalamount = finalamount + item1;
    if(input == 2)
        finalamount = finalamount + item2;
    if(input == 3)
        finalamount = finalamount + item3;
    if(input == 4)
        finalamount = finalamount + item4;
}
public void Finalcalculations()
{
    double temp;
    temp = finalamount * (.09);
    finalamount = temp + 200.00;
}
public void Display()
{
    System.out.println("Last Weeks earnings are $" + finalamount);
}
}

//CalculatorTest.java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalculatorTest {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.out.println("Sales Commission Calculator");
    for(int i = 0; i != -1; i++)
    {
        int input;
        SalesComissionCalculator Person = new SalesComissionCalculator();
        Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input a number for the item sold. Item 1 would be ex: 1");
        System.out.println("Item 2 = 2, Item 3 = 3, Item 4 = 4.");
        System.out.println("To end the loop type in -1");
        input = userinput.nextInt();
        if(input != -1)
        {
            Person.Additem(input);
        }
        if(input == -1)
        {
            Person.Display();
            break;
        }
    }
}

}
```

I made a silly mistake by creating an object in the loop so it never actually had a value. Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Use a debugger, step through the code and find out

Comment: Please provide an example of sample input and output.

Comment: Convention would be to have lowercase instance names. ie change `Person` to `person`.

Comment: Title is changed to reflect accurate question or reason for the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line:

```
SalesComissionCalculator Person = new SalesComissionCalculator();
```

is inside the for loop. Therefore it is creating a new person object (with a `finalamount` of 0.0) every time it goes through the loop to read the next input. Move that line above the loop so that you only create the person once in the method.

Comment: 1+, also mention that his loop looks to be better implemented as a while loop without the `break`.

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly. Long hours on the computer have the tendency to let me make easy mistakes.

Comment: @BrettHolmes - take a break then. Watch some of my videos if you wish to have a laugh. Go for a walk etc.

Comment: I don't deserve 6 upvotes for pointing out something this obvious guys, come on.

Answer (score 2):

This is where a debugger would help you solve it for yourself.

Every time you loop, you create a new `SalesComissionCalculator` and each time, this "Person" starts with a  total of 0.0 so when you print it, it will be 0.0.

The simple solution is to move it outside the loop so that you have one object and it accumulates the inputs you make.

Answer (score -1):

First of all make sure you put this line of code outside the loop since each time a new object is created for it.

SalesComissionCalculator Person = new SalesComissionCalculator();
All the best!!